# Table not aligning with layer objects

Tags: mapinfo, excel

I am new to GIS.
I am using Mapinfo V17.0.2
I am creating a cemetery plot. I have created many rows of polygons to shape the desired areas for burials. 
My table looks a little like this;

ID | Lot | Sector | Long | Lat |Cemetery

---

1  | A1 | JE | 664915.21 | 6334263.07 | GA

---

I have finished manually entering Row and Lot into one of my table columns [Lot]; ie. A1, A2....W23,W24. ( If there is an easier way I'd be much appreciative)
Using a raster image of the area I Extracted the Long and Lat.

Now I needed different 'Sector's within, Like Anglican, Jewish etc..
'AN' & 'JE' respectively.
Now I entered the JE manually, like 10 entries. I knew I could export these to excel, .csv format and then autofill the remainder with 'AN'... I went to Data > Filter and showed the top entries with JE so i could autofill the rest with AN. Now what I didn't know was by doing this when I opened the table back into Mapinfo, all the layer objects looked correct but my data was all over the place. where A1 should of been was now J26 , this was because I filtered the data in excel.

How can I resolve this, or do I need to re-start my manual Row and Lot entries again?

Looking at my structure and how I started to create my polygons, I am not sure how to fix this. As I created polygons for the cemeteries that are existing and then creating polygons for empty plots so my table strucure already wasn't in order of A1..A2..A3 etc. It would of looked more like; J3..J4..E5..E12..A1
Another day just manually inputting the Row and Lot back in I'd say. :/

Comment: You cannot have polygons in a .CSV file. So how did the export/import work? Do you have the polygons in another table?

Comment: So each polygon I drew, created a row in my table. Each polygon had its own attributes; ID, Lot, X, Y, Location etc. So when to export that data out into .CSV i had all that data of each field; but when i went to filter the columns.. exporting the table back into Mapinfo each polygon had the wrong attributes.. where A1 should of been, it was now J3 or something. As I moved the table around in excel it moved the associated placements when moved back into Mapinfo.
I didn't move any polygons per say, just the data it held within.

Comment: So I have been fiddling with buttons, :) , and if i select a few polygons at a time that associate with the Row .. i.e Select all polygons in Row A. I open the query table, in the Sort and Filter > Add to Map. Call it Row_A and add to existing map layer. I can than filter the 'long' column , biggest to smallest ( from top row to bottom row) and then do Update Column and add in "A"&rowid to the value box to create to right order of A1, A2.
I have gone from individual polygons to now altering particular Rows. Faster, but only way to stop say B1 becoming another A increment. No .csv needed.